# Automatic slide advance with AtBeginSection

Tags: beamer, transition

I am using automatic slide advance (transduration) with  \AtBeginSection, the problem is it stops at the next local TOC, i want it to stop at the end of the curent slide, not at the local TOC.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\AtBeginSection[]
{
    \begin{frame}<beamer>
        \frametitle{contents}%to allow TOC break
\tableofcontents
    \end{frame}
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Contents}
\tableofcontents
    \end{frame}
\section{section one}
\begin{frame}
Frame1
\end{frame}
\section{section two}
\begin{frame}
    Frame2
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}\transfade<-+>
        \transduration{1}%i want this to stop at the end of the slide
        \node<1-> (img1) {\includegraphics[clip, trim=.0cm .0cm .0cm .0cm, height=\textheight,width=\textwidth, keepaspectratio]{example-image}};       
        \node<2-> (img2) {\includegraphics[clip, trim=.0cm .0cm .0cm .0cm, height=\textheight,width=\textwidth, keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}};
        \node<3-> (img3) {\includegraphics[clip, trim=.0cm .0cm .0cm .0cm, height=\textheight,width=\textwidth, keepaspectratio]{example-image-b}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\section{section three}
\begin{frame}
    Frame3
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```